# Firebase promise - Query.once failed: Was called with 1 argument. Expects at least 2

Tags: javascript, firebase

I'm trying to fill an array with some data from Firebase using promises. Here's the DB structure:

```
- domain name(or something)
  |--highscore
     |--Foo: 50
     |--Bar: 60
```

The code:

```
var arr=[];
highscoreRef.child('highscore').once('value').then(function(snapshot) {
    snapshot.forEach(function(data) {
    arr.push({playerName: data.key(), score: data.val()});
    });
  }, function(error) {
     console.error(error);
});
```

I get `Uncaught Error: Query.once failed: Was called with 1 argument. Expects at least 2.`

Does that mean I have to add at least 2 properties to Foo and Bar? Ex. *Foo = {playerName: name, score: 50}*

The current DB arrangement fits my needs.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I've used the `once()` promise without problems. Give me a moment to set up a jsfiddle/jsbin.

Comment: Works for me: http://jsbin.com/qiranu/edit?js,console. Are you using Firebase JavaScript SDK version 2.4 or later (that's where promises were introduced).

Comment: I normally consider it a typo, which is why I comment (to cast a close-vote once it's confirmed). But you may be right, given the error message, others might find this.

Comment: @Frank van Puffelen, thanks for your quick reply! The idea of checking which version I was using *never* crossed my mind. And it was 2.2.1. I copied the CDN from one of the tutorials and forgot about checking there. My bad.
Anyway I can mark your comment as an answer?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen: Yeah, in this case, it's useful.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**This error message happens when you try to use the Promisified API on a pre-Promisified SDK.**

Callbacks (that other answers have suggested) will work on any 2.x version of the Firebase SDK.

We introduced an alternative syntax using promises in Firebase's JavaScript SDK version 2.4. See an example of `once().then()` in this jsbin: http://jsbin.com/qiranu/edit?js,console

Are you using Firebase JavaScript SDK version 2.4 or later (that's where promises were introduced)?

Comment: Turned out I was using an older SDK version(2.2.1). I need to pay attention to such details from now on. Thanks again!

Comment: You say "we," so if you mean that literally (e.g., you're on the project), it may be worth updating the docs to show that `successCallback` is now optiona.

Comment: Yup. That update is in the pipeline (I actually thought it'd gone out already, but clearly it hasn't). We changed most methods (e.g. [set()](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/api/firebase/set.html) at the same time the feature came out, but somehow forgot `once()`.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `then`. Once takes a callback function as the second parameter:

https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/api/query/once.html

```
var arr=[];
highscoreRef.child('highscore').once('value', function(snapshot) {
    snapshot.forEach(function(data) {
    arr.push({playerName: data.key(), score: data.val()});
    });
  }, function(error) {
     console.error(error);
});
```

Comment: I know, but [this](https://www.firebase.com/blog/2016-01-21-keeping-our-promises.html) article says I can use `then` after `once()`.

Comment: @JeremyJackson callbacks will indeed work on any 2.x version of the Firebase SDK. But we introduced an alternative syntax using promises in Firebase's JavaScript SDK version 2.4. That's what OP is trying to use.