# Can't get promises to work on .set() in Firebase

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, promise

I am learning angularjs and firebase, and I am having some trouble getting the promises to work. It works with every angularfire function like `$createUser`, but not on other web api functions like `.set()`. According to the documentation, `.set()` should return a promise

Here is my stripped code:

controller.js

```
function setUserInformation(data) {
    return usersService.addUserData(data.uid, user)
        .then(function (userData) {
            //do something
        })
        .catch(function(error) {
            // handle error
        });
}
```

usersService.js

```
function addUserData(uid, user) {
            return firebaseDataService.users.child(uid).set({ name: user.name });
        }
```

`firebaseDataService.users` is just a reference to my the firebase url:

```
firebaseDataService.users = new Firebase(MY_URL + '/users');
```

I get the following error message:

```
angular.js:12416 TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined
    at setUserInformation (auth.controller.js:31)
    at auth.controller.js:23
    at angular.js:14634
    at n.$eval (angular.js:15916)
    at n.$digest (angular.js:15727)
    at angular.js:15955
    at e (angular.js:5490)
    at angular.js:5762
```

Anyone wanna point me in the right direction?

Thanks!

Comment: does `set` return a promise? [docs](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/api/firebase/set.html) suggest it takes a callback. edit //no, can do both apparently

Comment: Yeah. Its supposed to support both. It works fine using a callback, but i prefer to use promises for readability.

Comment: promises were added recently I think. What version are you using?

Comment: Currently using version 2.2.4

Comment: It was introduced in [2.4.0](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/changelog.html). Try using that one or later.

Comment: That fixed it right up. I read somewhere that promises were added after 2.2, but that was obviously wrong. Thanks :)

Comment: Did you know there's an angular firebase implementation? https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/

Comment: Yeah, I am using it alongside the web API as they don't rule each other out, as far as I'm aware.

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35526205/firebase-promise-query-once-failed-was-called-with-1-argument-expects-at-lea/35526844#35526844