# Understanding Firebase promises API

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase

So, here's my code:

```
var root = new Firebase( "https://dummydummydummy.firebaseio.com/" );
var user = root.child("people").child(service).child(id);
user.once("value").then(function(snapshot){
   console.log( snapshot.val() );
});
```

This gives me an error:

```
Query.once failed: Was called with 1 argument. Expects at least 2.
```

even though my Firebase version is 2.4.2.

JSBin: http://jsbin.com/yivelugage/1/edit?js,console

Screenshot:
[image]

What's wrong here? :)

Comment: Firebase don't return a promise it use callbacks `user.once("value", function(snapshot) {`

Comment: @jcubic I differ: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35526205/firebase-promise-query-once-failed-was-called-with-1-argument-expects-at-lea

Comment: @jcubic https://www.firebase.com/blog/2016-01-21-keeping-our-promises.html

Comment: @LittleChild that sounds weird. Can you reproduce it in a site like jsfiddle/jsbin, so that I can have a look?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen see JSBin

Comment: Your JSBin code succeeds without error for me.

Comment: @JLRishe I know :/ Heisenbug?

Comment: The only sensible explanation I can think of is that the version of Firebase in your project is older than 2.4. Can you double-check that? Perhaps try replacing the files you have?

Comment: @JLRishe this is in my `package.json` : `"firebase": "^2.4.2",` and I only started this project  yesterday so...

Comment: It is odd, that on the second line of attached screenshot it is said `;var fb=fb||"2.3.1"`

Comment: The jsbin works for me. Does it really fail for you? If so, can you have a look at the network tab in the developer tools to see what version of the Firebase client it gets? It retrieves `https://cdn.firebase.com/js/client/2.4.1/firebase.js` for me, which is a version that has promises.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen well I am using it server side on node so.. how do I do that? :) JSBin passes. My code in Node fails.

Comment: You may have firebase with different version, than mentioned in package.json. Try run `npm list firebase` in you project's directory and make sure, that it returns version 2.4.2 or higher.

Comment: @k10der ` firebase@2.4.2 `

Comment: Even though you've changed the version in `package.json`, npm might still be trippin. Try do a `rm -rf node_modules` and then an `npm i`.