# Firebase Query.Once failed on Firefox and Google Chrome console, but not it JS Bin website

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a problem with firebase, it read data using 'once', but it shows me `Uncaught Error: Query.once failed: Was called with 1 argument. Expects at least 2` on Firefox console and Google Chrome, but the source code on JS Bin there's no error.
I got the code from here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/35526844/6780268
I copy the code in bracket, i try 2 different firebase.js, but still show me nothing.

```
var ref = new Firebase('https://stackoverflow.firebaseio.com/35526205');
        ref.child('Highscore').once('value').then(function(snapshot) {
            console.log(snapshot.val());
        });
```

Is this normal? And how to fix this problem?
Sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 0):

You're likely using a different/newer version of Firebase than the one in [the jsbin in the link](https://jsbin.com/qiranu/edit?js,console).

In newer versions of Firebase, you get a reference to the same database location with:

```
firebase.initializeApp({ databaseURL: "https://stackoverflow.firebaseio.com" });
var ref = firebase.database().ref("35526205");
```

I recommend reading the [Firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/start), the [migration guide](https://firebase.google.com/support/guides/firebase-web), and the [web codelab](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/firebase-web/).